# Is a formula with no bound variables an atomic formula even if it contains a Quantifier?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

For example my understanding is:

∃(P(x)) contains no bound variables even though we have a quantifier, it also always evaluates to either true or false.

Does this mean that it is an atomic formula?

Thanks

Comment: There are grammars for the predicate calculus. And so in analogy, you can have atomic formulae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An atomic formula has the form $R(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ or $t_1 = t_2$ (where $R$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ are terms). Nothing else is an atomic formula.

Now a complex formula $\varphi$ may be *logically equivalent* to an atomic formula. But that does not make $\varphi$ itself atomic.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you. Edit: I'm not sure why you got a down vote, I'm not able to vote as I have just created my account :(

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Math Stackexchange! If my answer settles your question,  you should "accept" it by clicking the green check mark on the left.

Comment: @OmjjICmA Don't worry, I'm not concerned about the voting  - I don't need the reputation! - I  was just surprised, since what I wrote seems uncontroversial...